# Content Provider for Network Storage

Tags: android-contentprovider, nfs, cifs

With most Android devices, mounting CIFS or NFS is only possible when the devices is rooted.
The question is, if it is possible to create a Android Content Provider which offers Pictures and Videos from the Network Storage (Samba) with the URIs as the internal storage does (i.e. MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI which is usually used for SD Cards).

Couldn't find any solution to this topic - maybe I've overseen a show stopper?!

Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most existing file manager are doing it through local http. They open the stream of interest, then listen for a http connection on a specific port to feed it with that stream.